# Is there a way to choose a null value in combo box of ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a following problem in a ASP.NET MVC application example.

In this example I've created a small database with two tables.

[image: Database used in example]

Based on this database, I used code first approach to create model in application, and then created two controllers, PackagesController and DangerInfoesController.

The problem occurs when I want to create new package. Problem is that I'm forced to select from DangerID combo box, even though that field is optional.

[image: Mandatory instead of optional]

Is there a way to allow this combo box to choose a null value?

EDIT (requested by amaldec23): This is the code of View/Packages/Create.cshtml

```
@model asp_example.Models.Package

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Package</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PackageID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PackageID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PackageID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DangerID, "DangerID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("DangerID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DangerID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Can you please post how you are loading combo in view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. All that was needed is to change this

```
@Html.DropDownList("DangerID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

into this

```
@Html.DropDownList("DangerID", null, "None.", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```